Loading parallel PostgreSQL layers with PyQGIS
I want to load a large number of PostgreSQL layers using PyQGIS.
When I load the layers using threads, it creates as many connections as there are layers. For example, if I have 38 layers, I end up with 38 connections to the database.
However, when I load the layers without using threads, for 38 layers, I only have 5 connections to the database.
Below, this is my code without Thread
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(*list_info_connection)
uri.setParam("key", "id")
uri.setParam("checkPrimaryKeyUnicity", "1")

project = QgsProject().instance()

for i in liste:
    uri.setDataSource("dw_topo", i[2], "geom")
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), i[0], "postgres")
    project.addMapLayer(layer)

Have an idea why?

I think you should use a threaded connection pool but I do not know how to do that with PyQGIS. There seem to be special libraries for that purpose https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-postgresql-connection-pooling-using-psycopg2/.

If you open 38 simultaneous connections it can't use less than 38 connections. QGis uses a pool to keep the number down - but 38 isn't that many for a decent server
